# How to present a view controller from an external framework in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have made a framework with a view controller named "AuthenticationViewController.h" with nib "AuthenticationViewController.xib". And a sample project to test have used to present AuthenticationViewController.
In `Objective-C`:

```
NSString *frameworkDirPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath];
NSString *frameworkBundlePath = [frameworkDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxx.framework"];
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
AuthenticationViewController *authenticationViewController = [[AuthenticationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AuthenticationViewController" bundle:frameworkBundle];
authenticationViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:authenticationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which works fine for me.

But when I use following code in `Swift`:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "xxx")

let authViewControler :AuthenticationViewController = AuthenticationViewController.init(nibName: "AuthenticationViewController", bundle: frameworkBundle)
authViewControler.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(authViewControler, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The app crashes with error:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'AuthenticationViewController''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSBundle(identifier: "SendOTPFramework")`,Not `NSBundle(path: <#T##String#>)`?Are you sure there is an available identifier?You used different function in different lang.

Comment: Is the "identifier" the bundle identifier of the framework included in the project. Or the framework name included.

Comment: @HussainChhatriwala The bundle identifier of the framework. You can also use path function in swift.

Comment: The above worked able to open the controller. but still app gets crashed after few sec on app delegate without any crash logs.

Comment: See what you did in AuthenticationViewController delegate.

Comment: had made a protocol with two methods in it for success and failure.

Comment: the code worked for objective c project but failed in swift.

Comment: I guessed.Swift is stricter than OC.If you get an unexpected value,it will crash.So check the types and nil value.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for swift 5 and using the name of the class instead of the framework identifier:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: AuthenticationViewController.self)
    let VC = AuthenticationViewController(nibName: "AuthenticationView", bundle: bundle)
    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It is also needed no connect the root view of the Xib to the file owner as outlet.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 13, Swift 5.5 and iOS 15**.

Your storyboard from Framework **SDKStoryboard** and your vc name in that storyboard **HelloLogger**

```
//Working fine
let s = UIStoryboard(name: "SDKStoryboard", bundle: Bundle(for: HelloLogger.self))
let vc = s.instantiateInitialViewController()!
//self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) //To present VC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) //Push VC
```

If you want another style [How to show View Controller from Framework(SDK) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235816/how-to-show-view-controller-from-frameworksdk-in-swift/69989994#69989994)