# How to show View Controller from Framework(SDK) in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, frameworks

I have my own generated Framework (SDK) in Objective C. Which is used in my Swift iOS Project. I want to call my Iinitial controller **CCInitViewController** (see the first image) from my SDK on click of Button (which is in App Controller) (see the second image).

So what kind of changes want to do in my code? Or any method I have to write in my SDK's .m file n call it in my project.

First image:

[image: My App Controller Contains Pay Button]

Second image:

[image]

I tried following Code :

```
@IBAction func payClicked(_ sender: Any)
{
    let cont = CCInitViewController(position: self)
    self.present(cont!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

it opens my controller `(CCInitViewController)` but no any internal content shows (Like Text Fields and Next Button) its blank.

Comment: you want to open a view of the app from the SKD or I misunderstood?

Comment: @Ivan NO, My SDK Containds 3 Views, in which i want to open my inital view of SDK From app, which is using my SDK.

Comment: It looks like this question has substantially changed its theme since it attracted answers. Please don't do that. Instead, ask a new question (with more detail than your most recent one!).

Comment: I have rolled this back to the question it was when it received answers, and added an image that was missing.

Comment: @MayurShinde Have you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode 13, Swift 5.5 and iOS 15**.

Your storyboard from Framework **SDKStoryboard** and your **vc** name in that storyboard **HelloLogger**

```
//Workign fine
if let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BlazeTuyaSDK", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
   let bundle = (Bundle(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString) as URL))
   let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SDKStoryboard", bundle: bundle)
   let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HelloLogger")
   self.show(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

If you want another style [How to present a view controller from an external framework in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626721/how-to-present-a-view-controller-from-an-external-framework-in-swift/69989961#69989961)

Answer (score 0):

All the times I made SDKs I have a Main class which usually is named with the same name as the Framework, which have an start method that opens the first view of the Framework (like if you start a "subapp" inside your app)

Comment: @Iven Exactly, i want that start method that opens the first view of my Framework. Then i can call it from Parent app to open my Framework. Can you please help out for that

Answer (score 0):

You can take UIViewController when user init your frameworks main class and you can keep that viewcontroller among your application to show your framework's controller on that user's viewController. I have did that like this and even in mopub its doing like that.

```
/// user side code should look like this

let frameWork = MyFramework(controller: self)

/// your framework should look like this.

    class MyFramework {
        
         var rootController: UIViewController?
    
         init(controller: UIViewController) {
               self.rootController = controller
         }
    
         func showController() {
             self.rootController?.present(myFrameworkController, true, nil)
         }
    }
```

I hope you got my point.

Comment: I got it, but can you give me same in Objective C ?? Because my SDK code is in Objective C.